# How to get username with symmetric key work?

Tags: web-services, security, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-ws

I have web service that wrap an ejb layer that use roleallowed annotation and jdbc realm .
In order to make the client authentification work from my swing client I Enabled Username authentication with symmetric keys (client+server) and set up my callback handler (client) .
When I run the client and try to acces a protected method I get this exception :

```
Grave: WSSTUBE0025: Error in Verifying Security in the Inbound Message.
com.sun.xml.wss.impl.PolicyViolationException: ERROR: No security header found in the message
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.policy.verifier.MessagePolicyVerifier.verifyPolicy(MessagePolicyVerifier.java:138)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient.createMessage(SecurityRecipient.java:1003)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient.validateMessage(SecurityRecipient.java:248)
```

and in server side i get :

```
Key used to decrypt EncryptedKey cannot be null
com.sun.xml.wss.logging.impl.opt.crypto Error occured while decrypting EncryptedKey     


WSITPVD0035: Error in Verifying Security in Inbound Message. com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: Invalid Security Header at
```

and

```
com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.util.SOAPUtil.newSOAPFaultException(SOAPUtil.java:159) at 
    com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.EncryptedKey.getKey(EncryptedKey.java:354) at 
    com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.KeySelectorImpl.resolveDirectReference(KeySelectorImpl.java:540) at 
    com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.processor.SecurityTokenProcessor.processDirectReference(SecurityTokenProcessor.java:267) at 
    com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.processor.SecurityTokenProcessor.resolveReference(SecurityTokenProcessor.java:143) at 
    com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.processor.KeyInfoProcessor.processKeyInfo(KeyInfoProcessor.java:152) at 
    com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.processor.KeyInfoProcessor.getKey(KeyInfoProcessor.java:132) at 
    com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.EncryptedData.process(EncryptedData.java:156) at 
    com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.EncryptedData.<init>(EncryptedData.java:113) at 
    com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient.handleSecurityHeader(SecurityRecipient.java:458) at 
    com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient.cacheHeaders(SecurityRecipient.java:291) at 
    com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient.validateMessage(SecurityRecipient.java:241) at 
    com.sun.xml.wss.provider.wsit.WSITServerAuthContext.verifyInboundMessage(WSITServerAuthContext.java:588) at 
    com.sun.xml.wss.provider.wsit.WSITServerAuthContext.validateRequest(WSITServerAuthContext.java:361) at 
    com.sun.xml.wss.provider.wsit.WSITServerAuthContext.validateRequest(WSITServerAuthContext.java:264) at 
    com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:173) at 
    com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:144) at 
    com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119) at 
    com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:961) at 
    com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:910) at 
    com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:873) at 
    com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:775) at 
    com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:386) at 
    com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:640) at 
    com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:263) at 
    com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:163) at 
    org.glassfish.webservices.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.handlePost(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:120) at 
    org.glassfish.webservices.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.invoke(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:91) at 
    org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.dispatchToEjbEndpoint(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:200) at 
    org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.service(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:131) at 
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770) at 
    com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(ServletAdapter.java:1059) at 
    com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter$FilterChainImpl.invokeFilterChain(ServletAdapter.java:999) at 
    com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.doService(ServletAdapter.java:434) at 
    com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.service(ServletAdapter.java:384) at 
    com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179) at 
    com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117) at 
    com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354) at 
    com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195) at 
    com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849) at 
    com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746) at 
    com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045) at 
    com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228) at 
    com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137) at
```

This is my first time with webservice security and it's possible that i forgot a basic thing to add .

Can you help me ?

Thanks .

**Edit:**
this the web service client xml :
*deleted cause lack of space*
**and server side**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<definitions 
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" name="custom_ws" targetNamespace="http://ejb/" xmlns:tns="http://ejb/" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:fi="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/wsit/2006/09/policy/fastinfoset/service" xmlns:tcp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/wsit/2006/09/policy/soaptcp/service" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702" xmlns:sc="http://schemas.sun.com/2006/03/wss/server" xmlns:wspp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/wsit/policy" 
>
    <message name="hmd"/>
    <message name="hmdResponse"/>
    <portType name="custom_ws">
        <operation name="hmd">
            <input message="tns:hmd"/>
            <output message="tns:hmdResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="custom_wsPortBinding" type="tns:custom_ws">
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#custom_wsPortBindingPolicy"/>
        <operation name="hmd">
            <input>
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#custom_wsPortBinding_hmd_Input_Policy"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#custom_wsPortBinding_hmd_Output_Policy"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="custom_ws">
        <port name="custom_wsPort" binding="tns:custom_wsPortBinding"/>
    </service>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="custom_wsPortBindingPolicy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <wsam:Addressing wsp:Optional="false"/>
                <sp:SymmetricBinding>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:ProtectionToken>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Never">
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                                        <sp:RequireIssuerSerialReference/>
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:X509Token>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:ProtectionToken>
                        <sp:Layout>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Strict/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:Layout>
                        <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                        <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
                        <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Basic128/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:SymmetricBinding>
                <sp:Wss11>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
                        <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint/>
                        <sp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey/>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:Wss11>
                <sp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:WssUsernameToken10/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:UsernameToken>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>
                <sc:KeyStore wspp:visibility="private" location="C:\glassfish312\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\keystore.jks" type="JKS" storepass="changeit" alias="xws-security-server"/>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="custom_wsPortBinding_hmd_Input_Policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <sp:EncryptedParts>
                    <sp:Body/>
                </sp:EncryptedParts>
                <sp:SignedParts>
                    <sp:Body/>
                    <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="AckRequested" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="SequenceAcknowledgement" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="Sequence" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="CreateSequence" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702"/>
                </sp:SignedParts>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="custom_wsPortBinding_hmd_Output_Policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <sp:EncryptedParts>
                    <sp:Body/>
                </sp:EncryptedParts>
                <sp:SignedParts>
                    <sp:Body/>
                    <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="AckRequested" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="SequenceAcknowledgement" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="Sequence" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702"/>
                    <sp:Header Name="CreateSequence" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702"/>
                </sp:SignedParts>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
</definitions>
```

**Edit 2**
I added part that seem missing to the client but its still not working , i get the same exception with a lot of warning

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.2-b13 (branches/2.2-6964; 2012-01-09T18:04:18+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.6-promoted-b20 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. --><!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.2-b13 (branches/2.2-6964; 2012-01-09T18:04:18+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.6-promoted-b20 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. -->
    <definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://ejb/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://ejb/" name="custom_ws" xmlns:sc="http://schemas.sun.com/2006/03/wss/client" xmlns:wspp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/wsit/policy">
        <types>
            <xsd:schema>
                <xsd:import namespace="http://ejb/" schemaLocation="http://myurl.net:8080/custom_ws/custom_ws?xsd=1"/>
            </xsd:schema>
        </types>
        <message name="hmd">
            <part name="parameters" element="tns:hmd"/>
        </message>
        <message name="hmdResponse">
            <part name="parameters" element="tns:hmdResponse"/>
        </message>
        <portType name="custom_ws">
            <operation name="hmd">
                <input wsam:Action="http://ejb/custom_ws/hmdRequest" message="tns:hmd"/>
                <output wsam:Action="http://ejb/custom_ws/hmdResponse" message="tns:hmdResponse"/>
            </operation>
        </portType>
        <binding name="custom_wsPortBinding" type="tns:custom_ws">
            <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#custom_wsPortBindingPolicy"/>
            <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
            <operation name="hmd">
                <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
                <input>
                    <soap:body use="literal"/>
                </input>
                <output>
                    <soap:body use="literal"/>
                </output>
            </operation>
        </binding>
        <service name="custom_ws">
            <port name="custom_wsPort" binding="tns:custom_wsPortBinding">
                <soap:address location="http://my_url.net:8080/custom_ws/custom_ws"/>
            </port>
        </service>
        <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="custom_wsPortBindingPolicy">
            <wsp:ExactlyOne>
                <wsp:All>
                   <wsam:Addressing wsp:Optional="false"/>
                    <wsp:SymmetricBinding>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <wsp:ProtectionToken>
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <wsp:X509Token wsp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Never">
                                        <wsp:Policy>
                                            <wsp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                                            <wsp:RequireIssuerSerialReference/>
                                        </wsp:Policy>
                                    </wsp:X509Token>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </wsp:ProtectionToken>
                            <wsp:Layout>
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <wsp:Strict/>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </wsp:Layout>
                            <wsp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                            <wsp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
                            <wsp:AlgorithmSuite>
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <wsp:Basic128/>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </wsp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </wsp:SymmetricBinding>
                    <wsp:Wss11>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <wsp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
                            <wsp:MustSupportRefThumbprint/>
                            <wsp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </wsp:Wss11>
                    <wsp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <wsp:UsernameToken wsp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <wsp:WssUsernameToken10/>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </wsp:UsernameToken>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </wsp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>

                    <sc:TrustStore wspp:visibility="private" location="C:\glassfish312\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\cacerts.jks" type="JKS" storepass="changeit" peeralias="xws-security-server"/>
                    <sc:CallbackHandlerConfiguration wspp:visibility="private">
                        <sc:CallbackHandler name="usernameHandler" classname="Gui.ociCallBackHandler"/>
                        <sc:CallbackHandler name="passwordHandler" classname="Gui.ociCallBackHandler"/>
                    </sc:CallbackHandlerConfiguration>
                </wsp:All>
            </wsp:ExactlyOne>
        </wsp:Policy>
    </definitions>
```

warning
*delted cause lack of space*

**Edit 3**
this the second try with the xml client file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.2-b13 (branches/2.2-6964; 2012-01-09T18:04:18+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.6-promoted-b20 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. --><!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.2-b13 (branches/2.2-6964; 2012-01-09T18:04:18+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.6-promoted-b20 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. -->
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://ejb/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://ejb/" name="custom_ws" xmlns:sc="http://schemas.sun.com/2006/03/wss/client" xmlns:wspp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/wsit/policy">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://ejb/" schemaLocation="http://my_url.net:8080/custom_ws/custom_ws?xsd=1"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="hmd" />
    <message name="hmdResponse" />
    <portType name="custom_ws">
        <operation name="hmd">
            <input message="tns:hmd" />
            <output message="tns:hmdResponse" />
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="custom_wsPortBinding" type="tns:custom_ws">
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#custom_wsPortBindingPolicy" />
        <operation name="hmd">
            <input>
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#custom_wsPortBinding_hmd_Input_Policy" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#custom_wsPortBinding_hmd_Output_Policy" />
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="custom_ws">
        <port name="custom_wsPort" binding="tns:custom_wsPortBinding" />
    </service>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="custom_wsPortBindingPolicy">
        <wsp:All>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <wsp:ExactlyOne>
                    <wsp:All>
                        <sc:TrustStore wspp:visibility="private" location="C:\glassfish312\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\cacerts.jks" type="JKS" storepass="changeit" peeralias="xws-security-server" />
                        <sc:CallbackHandlerConfiguration wspp:visibility="private">
                            <sc:CallbackHandler name="usernameHandler" classname="Gui.ociCallBackHandler" />
                            <sc:CallbackHandler name="passwordHandler" classname="Gui.ociCallBackHandler" />
                        </sc:CallbackHandlerConfiguration>
                    </wsp:All>
                </wsp:ExactlyOne>
            </wsp:Policy>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <wsp:ExactlyOne>
                    <wsp:All>
                        <wsam:Addressing wsp:Optional="false" />
                        <wsp:SymmetricBinding>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <wsp:ProtectionToken>
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <wsp:X509Token wsp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Never">
                                            <wsp:Policy>
                                                <wsp:WssX509V3Token10 />
                                                <wsp:RequireIssuerSerialReference />
                                            </wsp:Policy>
                                        </wsp:X509Token>
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </wsp:ProtectionToken>
                                <wsp:Layout>
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <wsp:Strict />
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </wsp:Layout>
                                <wsp:IncludeTimestamp />
                                <wsp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody />
                                <wsp:AlgorithmSuite>
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <wsp:Basic128 />
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </wsp:AlgorithmSuite>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </wsp:SymmetricBinding>
                        <wsp:Wss11>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <wsp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial />
                                <wsp:MustSupportRefThumbprint />
                                <wsp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey />
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </wsp:Wss11>
                        <wsp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <wsp:UsernameToken wsp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <wsp:WssUsernameToken10 />
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </wsp:UsernameToken>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </wsp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>
                        <sc:KeyStore wspp:visibility="private" location="C:\glassfish312\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\keystore.jks" type="JKS" storepass="changeit" alias="xws-security-server" />
                    </wsp:All>
                </wsp:ExactlyOne>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:Policy>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="custom_wsPortBinding_hmd_Input_Policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <wsp:EncryptedParts>
                    <wsp:Body />
                </wsp:EncryptedParts>
                <wsp:SignedParts>
                    <wsp:Body />
                    <wsp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <wsp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <wsp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <wsp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <wsp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <wsp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <wsp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <wsp:Header Name="AckRequested" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" />
                    <wsp:Header Name="SequenceAcknowledgement" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" />
                    <wsp:Header Name="Sequence" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" />
                    <wsp:Header Name="CreateSequence" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" />
                </wsp:SignedParts>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="custom_wsPortBinding_hmd_Output_Policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <wsp:EncryptedParts>
                    <wsp:Body />
                </wsp:EncryptedParts>
                <wsp:SignedParts>
                    <wsp:Body />
                    <wsp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <wsp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <wsp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <wsp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <wsp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <wsp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <wsp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <wsp:Header Name="AckRequested" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" />
                    <wsp:Header Name="SequenceAcknowledgement" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" />
                    <wsp:Header Name="Sequence" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" />
                    <wsp:Header Name="CreateSequence" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" />
                </wsp:SignedParts>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whoaaa. The client wsdl doesn't have ws-sec-policy. How is the client supposed to know to use it? The client and the server wsdl has to be identical, except in a few implementation detail. (for example the passwordcallback handler class name, but these can be hidden from a client)

Always use the published wsdl for the client, otherwise the whole contract of wsdl is pointless: client and server will talk in different languages so to speak.

Use the original wsdl on the client and put the callback specific policy in a wsit.xml.

EDIT:

without automatic wsit merging (I guess you use CXF, because Metro would have done it for you), you have to merge manually:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" name="custom_ws" targetNamespace="http://ejb/" xmlns:tns="http://ejb/" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:fi="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/wsit/2006/09/policy/fastinfoset/service" xmlns:tcp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/wsit/2006/09/policy/soaptcp/service" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702" xmlns:sc="http://schemas.sun.com/2006/03/wss/server" xmlns:wspp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/wsit/policy">
    <message name="hmd" />
    <message name="hmdResponse" />
    <portType name="custom_ws">
        <operation name="hmd">
            <input message="tns:hmd" />
            <output message="tns:hmdResponse" />
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="custom_wsPortBinding" type="tns:custom_ws">
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#custom_wsPortBindingPolicy" />
        <operation name="hmd">
            <input>
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#custom_wsPortBinding_hmd_Input_Policy" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#custom_wsPortBinding_hmd_Output_Policy" />
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="custom_ws">
        <port name="custom_wsPort" binding="tns:custom_wsPortBinding" />
    </service>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="custom_wsPortBindingPolicy">
        <wsp:All>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <wsp:ExactlyOne>
                    <wsp:All>
                        <sc:TrustStore wspp:visibility="private" location="C:\glassfish312\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\cacerts.jks" type="JKS" storepass="changeit" peeralias="xws-security-server" />
                        <sc:CallbackHandlerConfiguration wspp:visibility="private">
                            <sc:CallbackHandler name="usernameHandler" classname="Gui.ociCallBackHandler" />
                            <sc:CallbackHandler name="passwordHandler" classname="Gui.ociCallBackHandler" />
                        </sc:CallbackHandlerConfiguration>
                    </wsp:All>
                </wsp:ExactlyOne>
            </wsp:Policy>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <wsp:ExactlyOne>
                    <wsp:All>
                        <wsam:Addressing wsp:Optional="false" />
                        <sp:SymmetricBinding>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:ProtectionToken>
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Never">
                                            <wsp:Policy>
                                                <sp:WssX509V3Token10 />
                                                <sp:RequireIssuerSerialReference />
                                            </wsp:Policy>
                                        </sp:X509Token>
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:ProtectionToken>
                                <sp:Layout>
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <sp:Strict />
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:Layout>
                                <sp:IncludeTimestamp />
                                <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody />
                                <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <sp:Basic128 />
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:SymmetricBinding>
                        <sp:Wss11>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial />
                                <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint />
                                <sp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey />
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:Wss11>
                        <sp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                    <wsp:Policy>
                                        <sp:WssUsernameToken10 />
                                    </wsp:Policy>
                                </sp:UsernameToken>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>
                        <sc:KeyStore wspp:visibility="private" location="C:\glassfish312\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\keystore.jks" type="JKS" storepass="changeit" alias="xws-security-server" />
                    </wsp:All>
                </wsp:ExactlyOne>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:Policy>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="custom_wsPortBinding_hmd_Input_Policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <sp:EncryptedParts>
                    <sp:Body />
                </sp:EncryptedParts>
                <sp:SignedParts>
                    <sp:Body />
                    <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <sp:Header Name="AckRequested" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" />
                    <sp:Header Name="SequenceAcknowledgement" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" />
                    <sp:Header Name="Sequence" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" />
                    <sp:Header Name="CreateSequence" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" />
                </sp:SignedParts>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="custom_wsPortBinding_hmd_Output_Policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <sp:EncryptedParts>
                    <sp:Body />
                </sp:EncryptedParts>
                <sp:SignedParts>
                    <sp:Body />
                    <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    <sp:Header Name="AckRequested" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" />
                    <sp:Header Name="SequenceAcknowledgement" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" />
                    <sp:Header Name="Sequence" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" />
                    <sp:Header Name="CreateSequence" Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" />
                </sp:SignedParts>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
</definitions>
```

Hope it'll work. Notice the inclusion of the client policy. It might seem strange, but in the end it all makes sense.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-policy/ for full reference.

Comment: I'm using metro and netbeans .

Comment: then it should automatically generate and pick up the wsit files. Be sure to point the client code generation to an already deployed live wsdl url. It'll get the right config, which you can later modify with netbeans tools. (if you want to stay on the safe side avoid modifying the wsdl and wsit files manually)

Comment: It's not working.I have to change sp: to wsp: to makte it run and  when I execute it i get warning about the xml but I can't post them because the topic is limited in size :( . I feel that I'm doing things totaly wrong . Do I have really to modify the wsdl's client manually ? Can it be a certificat problem ?